# Do you have a negative sampling implementation for intent training in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

For the intent detection, do you have a negative sampling implementation on the machine learning algorithm of Dialogflow?

If yes, does Dialogflow get those negative samples from other intents?

If this is the case, then i will be eager create new intents to support negative sampling.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `sys.ignore` prefix to an intent name, then all matches to that intent will result in no match/default fallback intent.

Comment: Thanks, but i am just trying to understand the machine learning implementation of dialogflow.

Comment: If I didn't answer your question please clarify here, in a comment, or update your question.  if you found my answer useful please upvote and mark it as correct.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the machine learning algorithm of Dialogflow matthewayne. I mean, positive samples are in the "user says" part in an intent but where the negative samples come from? from other intents' "user says" samples?

Comment: General questions on how machine learning works are not appropriate for StackOverflow.  Here is Dialogflow's article on how their machine learning works: https://dialogflow.com/docs/machine-learning